# Azure window sever can't upload file from php

Tags: php, azure

i test on localhost and other websever it ok.

but when i upload in azure sever it can't uploadfile to folder

here is my code

```
    if(isset($_FILES['pic'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['pic']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['pic']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['pic']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploadimg/".$us_id.".jpg");
         echo "ican";

      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
```

but it echo "ican" ,i suspect it have permisson or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web app gives you permission to write to the root folder only. It looks like here you are writing to a "uploadimg" folder.

It is strongly recommended that you upload to Azure Blob Storage instead.

You can find instructions for PHP here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: that mean i can upload at wwwroot folder ?

Comment: Yes, your app should be able to write to the wwwroot folder which is the root of the site itself. Again the best approach would be to use blob storage. Hope this helps!

Comment: i change to upload to wwwroot but it not appear

Comment: Leave it empty. i.e.  move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"".$us_id.".jpg");

Comment: I setup a quick demo site here http://phpuploadtest.azurewebsites.net code can be found here https://github.com/joescars/PHPUpload

Comment: yes i use move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"".$us_id.".jpg");  but not work :(

Comment: Can you please let me know the error you are getting?

Comment: not error but file don't get into wwwroot folder like uploadimage folder

Comment: I would recommend comparing to the code I posted (or even using it) to see where your code differs and why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check whether you have created the folder named `uploadimg` in your root directory.

By default, Azure Web Apps do not display PHP errors, so if you do not have a `uploadimg` folder in your directory, the PHP process will raise a `Waring` exception and will not stop the process, so you can see "ican" and there is no pictures also.

Also you can add sentences:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

in your PHP script to show the exception messages for troubleshooting.

Comment: yes in my wwwroot folder have uploadimg and when i upload picture come to folder