# How can i upload file to azure wwwroot folder

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

I use this code

`move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$us_id.".jpg");`

but after run this script it not error but file not appear into folder ,how can it do?

before these, I test in localhost it work.

Comment: Make sure the folder is writable for the web user?

Comment: Don't know, never played with azure before

Answer (score 0):

**Edited based on @David's comments and Kudu's [Azure runtime environment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment)**

In a Cloud environment, saving files to the current filesystem of your Web App is not advised. If you simply upload your site through FTP, you might not have issues, but if you rely on [Continuous Integration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/) or automated deployment scenarios, your site folder might change or have content overwritten.

That is why, for storage of files that need to be accesed in the future or need to be permantently saved, you might want to use something like **Azure Blob Storage**. Not only is really cheap, but you can apply **CDN** over it for improving your files delivery.

Here is how to [use it on PHP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs/) and the [Azure SDK for PHP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question the OP asked: You're suggesting the use of blobs instead of web app storage, for durability. Web Apps have their own storage which is on a network share, shared between all running instances, and durable (I'm not referring to local scratch storage). Unless you delete your web app altogether, your storage isn't going anywhere. Everything under `d:\home\site` is on this durable share, and not on local scratch disk.

Comment: That's not correct. The durable share is not shared among if the container goes down and a new copy takes it's place nor on scaling up/out, you cannot rely on it for uploads. The OP is asking why an uploaded file is not appearing in the folder, assuming the upload PHP code is correct (there is no evidence of the full code), I'm explaning that in a Cloud paradigm, relying on the filesystem is not recommended, the file could not be there because the server serving the request might not be the same server that handled the upload even though his code might be correct.

Comment: For Azure Web Apps (formerly Web Sites), this is indeed how things work.

Comment: Point taken. I still believe from experience, that all static uploaded content should be on a separate Storage account, when you implement Continuous Integration or some automated deployment process, the site folder might get changed. Edited answer taking in account your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what `$file_tmp` contains, but... in an Azure Web App, the root folder is at `d:\home\site\wwwroot`. And you'll find the `%HOME%` environment variable set to `d:\home`.

Answer (score 0):

As I leverage your code at [Azure window sever can't upload file from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723519/azure-window-sever-cant-upload-file-from-php/35737700?noredirect=1#comment59156240_35737700) in my test project, it works perfectly on my side, even I don't value the `$us_id` in your code, the picture is still updated to the `uploadimg` folder with the name `.jpg`.

I suspect whether if your Web Apps's disk space has reached the limitation of your App Service plan.

As every App Service pricing tier has a limit disk space and will shared in all the web apps in this App Service plan. You can check the metric on dashboard page of your web app portal, e.g.
[image]

You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/ for details.